# Inverse of division in C?

Tags: c, binary

I want to make this division in C

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {

  float result;
  int val;

  val = 7;
  result = 1/(1 >> val);

}
```

but i get -2147483648 as result instead of 128.
How to obtain the right result from this division?

Comment: Can you please explain why you think the result should be `128`?

Comment: Hint: dividing 2 integers produce an integer as well...

Comment: According to this page https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/left-shift-right-shift-operators-c-cpp/ the right shift operator x >> y, is equivalent to x / (2^y). If thats true that means is 1/128, i want to get 128, with 1 / (1/128).

Comment: @SamuR: These are integers you're dealing with. 1/128 is not an integer. If you try to shift too far to the right, you get zero, not a fraction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(1 >> val)` shifts `1` "down" (towards the least significant bit) `val` (7) steps.

To get `128`, you want to shift it "up" (towards the most significant bit) `val` steps.

```
result = 1 / (1 << val);
```

Now you've got `1 / 128` ... which is `0`. Why? Because they are both integers. It doesn't matter that `result` is a `float`. To promote the division to a division of two `float`s, you need to make either operand a `float`. The other operand will then implicitly be converted to a `float` too.

```
result = 1.f / (1 << val);
```

`result` now becomes approximately `0.007812`.

Comment: 1/(1/128) = 128 which is what it appears the OP was going for but the shift is a substitute for divide with integers clearly wont work here.

Comment: @old_timer Yes. dividing by shifting down is familiar. You may be correct in that OP wanted 1/(1/128) instead of what was put in the question. Seems plausible.

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track,  1/(1/128) = 128, but you cannot use right shift as a substitute for divide (x/2 = x>>1) because it immediately shifts your 1 off the lsbit end.

And with C it fills in with zeros (well in this case).  So as pointed out 1/0 is undefined or in float a "properly signed infinity" or a fault.  Your promotion to float is after this divide by zero.

Now you could have done this and had it work with a roll your own float where you say put the point between bits 15 and 16 for example.  Let you work out the adjustments yourself.

For floating point (IEEE 754) you can't just shift it either to turn 1 into 1/128 you do not shift. you adjust the exponent and leave the fraction alone.

So this could be done with fixed point math no problem, just not like you have it here.

To see the problem do this

```
for(y=0,x=0x80;y<20;x>>=1,y++)
{
     printf("0x%02X %u\n",x,y);
}
```

In your case 1>>7 starts with a 0x01 you can repeat that experiment using x=0x01 as well and see what happens.

You did a divide by zero and you got what the compiler gave you for that (thinking compiler not hardware).

Did your compiler not complain?

```
test.c:5:17: warning: division by zero [-Wdiv-by-zero]
    5 |  return(float)(1/(1>>7));
      |
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 val = 7;
 1 >> val;
```

The above says to Right shift the value 1 by 7 positions. It will result 0
And so that in,

```
result = 1/(1 >> val);
```

result=1/0 which is an undefined situation. So that the result will misbehave